# Main Error Null pointer exception / Unable to run in command line either

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am creating a program that should ask the user in command line what he would like to sort using the SHell Sort method.

I have the shell sort method created but getting an error on my side when trying to run it.

I verified this worked fine when working on friends windows Client but still unable to run

```js
public class client{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  // Get the file name of the data set , and the number of runs
// for the data set from the command line
// Read in the file of N random Doubles from the command line and
// store in the array data []
// Build i n c r e m e n t s e q u e n c e arrays for this data set
// D e t e r m i n e the upper value of array based on h [ k ] <= 0.5* N
// h1 [] , h2 [] , h3 [] , h4 []
// h1 is the i n c r e m e n t s e q u e n c e : 1 ,2 ,4 ,8 ,16 ,32 ,...2^ i
// h2 is the i n c r e m e n t s e q u e n c e : 1 ,8 ,23 ,77 ,281 ,...4^ i +3*2^{ i -1} + 1
// h3 is the i n c r e m e n t s e q u e n c e : 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,6 ,8 ,9 ,12 ,...2^ p *3^ q
// h4 is the i n c r e m e n t s e q u ee n c e : 1 ,3 ,7 ,15 ,31 ,63 ,...2^ i - 1
// sort the array of N items with each s e q u e n c e j trials , timing each :
  int n=5;

  int h1 [] = new int [1000];
  int h2[] = new int[1000];

  int h3 [] = new int [1000];
  int h4[] = new int[1000];
  Comparable data[] = new Comparable[1000];
  while(n>0){
ShellSort study = new ShellSort ( data );
double start = System.nanoTime (); 
study.sortUsing (h1);
double duration1 = System.nanoTime () - start ;
start = System . nanoTime (); study.sortUsing ( h2 );
double duration2 = System . nanoTime () - start ;
start = System . nanoTime (); study . sortUsing ( h3 );
double duration3 = System . nanoTime () - start ;
start = System . nanoTime (); study . sortUsing ( h4 );
double duration4 = System . nanoTime () - start ;
// display results for an average g e n e r a t e d from at least
 }
 n--;
}
}
```

is the client

```js
import java.util.*;
public class ShellSort
{
private Comparable [] data ;
public ShellSort ( Comparable [] x )
{
data = new Comparable [x.length ];
for ( int i =0; i < x.length ; i++)
this.data [ i ] = x [ i ];
}
public void sortUsing ( int [] h )
{
// your code
  int n = data.length; 
  
        // Start with a big gap, then reduce the gap 
        for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) 
        { 
            // Do a gapped insertion sort for this gap size. 
            // The first gap elements a[0..gap-1] are already 
            // in gapped order keep adding one more element 
            // until the entire dataay is gap sorted 
            for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) 
            { 
                // add a[i] to the elements that have been gap 
                // sorted save a[i] in temp and make a hole at 
                // position i 
                Comparable temp = data[i]; 
  
                // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until 
                // the correct location for a[i] is found 
                int j; 
                for (j = i; j >= gap && less(temp,data[j-gap]); j -= gap)
                    data[j] = data[j - gap]; 
  
                // put temp (the original a[i]) in its correct 
                // location 
                data[j] = temp; 
            } 
        } 
        


}
private boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w)
{
return ( v.compareTo(w) < 0); }
private void exch(Comparable[] data, int i, int j )
{
Comparable t = data[i]; data[i] = data[j]; data[j]= t; }

}
```

Comment: Where is the `NPE`?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ShellSort.less(ShellSort.java:50)
 at ShellSort.sortUsing(ShellSort.java:36)
 at client.main(client.java:29)

Comment: Which line is it? Do you expect us to count and figure it out?

Comment: Comparable data[] = new Comparable[1000]; This intializes the array with all null values. i.e. data[0],...data[999] with null. If you expect it to have some non null value you must initialize it.

Comment: The code is suppose to be run in Command line and ask user for input ... But everytime i try to run it in command line the error i receive is " Error: Could not find or load main class client.java"

Comment: per instructions I should be able to:
- Create using "javac client.java"
- Run using "java client.java"
after that your user should be able to input the numbers to be sorted.

Comment: The correct command is `java client`. The .java part is only given to javac.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't fill comparables in array. They is set as nulls that's why you get NLP.

Because :

```
 Comparable data[] = new Comparable[1000];
```

contains all elements with value null as it is Object 
so actually for example :

```
  data[0] = null
  .
  .
  .
  data[999] = null;
```

And when invoking this method :

```
 private boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }
```

You are passing parameters as null and when you invoke something on null you get NullPointerExceptions.